# Can Pester v5 Mock command be called outside an It, Before or After block?

Tags: powershell, pester, pester-5

I have some old Pester v4 tests that are failing when I try to run them in Pester v5.

With Pester v4 I read that once `Mock` is called it will continue to apply for the rest of the `Describe` block, even if it was called within an `It` block.  So I would call it from the `Describe` block, outside of an `It` block, to make it obvious it didn't just apply to a single `It` block.

That behaviour which worked in Pester v4 doesn't seem to work in Pester v5.

This is the script I'm writing tests against, MyScriptToTest.ps1:

```
function Get-FirstText ()
{
    return 'Some text'
}

function Get-SecondText ()
{
    return 'Other text'
}

function Get-Text ()
{
    $a = Get-FirstText
    $b = Get-SecondText

    return "$a; $b"
}
```

And here are the tests, in MyScriptToTest.Tests.ps1:

```
BeforeAll {
    . (Join-Path $PSScriptRoot 'MyScriptToTest.ps1')
}

Describe 'Get-FirstText' {
    It 'returns text "Some text"' {
        $result = Get-FirstText
            $result | Should -Be 'Some text'
        } 
}

Describe 'Get-Text' {
    It 'returns text "Some text; Other text"' {
        Get-Text | Should -Be 'Some text; Other text'
        } 

    Mock Get-FirstText { return 'Mock text' }
    
    It 'returns text "Mock text; Other text" after mocking Get-FirstText' {
        Get-Text | Should -Be 'Mock text; Other text'
        } 
}
```

The Pester v5 test output is as follows:

```
Describing Get-FirstText
  [+] returns text "Some text" when called indirectly 13ms (8ms|5ms)

Describing Get-Text
  [+] returns text "Some text; Other text" 66ms (54ms|13ms)
  [-] returns text "Mock text; Other text" after mocking Get-FirstText 42ms (41ms|1ms)
   Expected strings to be the same, but they were different.
   String lengths are both 21.
   Strings differ at index 0.
   Expected: 'Mock text; Other text'
   But was:  'Some text; Other text'
              ^
   at Get-Text | Should -Be 'Mock text; Other text', C:\...\MyScriptToTest.Tests.ps1:20
   at <ScriptBlock>, C:\...\MyScriptToTest.Tests.ps1:20
Tests completed in 565ms
Tests Passed: 2, Failed: 1, Skipped: 0 NotRun: 0
```

However, if I move the `Mock` command into the `It` block then it works:

```
BeforeAll {
    . (Join-Path $PSScriptRoot 'MyScriptToTest.ps1')
}

Describe 'Get-FirstText' {
    It 'returns text "Some text"' {
        $result = Get-FirstText
            $result | Should -Be 'Some text'
        } 
}

Describe 'Get-Text' {
    It 'returns text "Some text; Other text"' {
        Get-Text | Should -Be 'Some text; Other text'
        }   
   
    It 'returns text "Mock text; Other text" after mocking Get-FirstText' {
        Mock Get-FirstText { return 'Mock text' }
        Get-Text | Should -Be 'Mock text; Other text'
        } 
}
```

I haven't figured out the new constraints around calling the `Mock` command in Pester v5.  Can the `Mock` command still be called within a `Describe` or `Context` block, outside of an `It` block?  Or does it now always have to be called within an `It` block?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The docs](https://pester.dev/docs/usage/mocking/#mocks-are-scoped-based-on-their-placement) describe the v5+ change of where `Mock` commands must (now) be placed (emphasis added):

> Mocks are no longer effective *in the whole `Describe` / `Context`* in which they were placed. Instead they will default to the block in which they were placed.

That is, a `Mock` command placed *directly* inside `Describe` or `Context` commands - as in the code in your question - is now effectively *ignored*.

To spell it out: In **Pester v5+**, for a **`Mock`** statement to be effective, it **must be placed inside one of the following constructs**:

- **Inside a `BeforeAll` command**, which therefore applies to *all tests in the same scope*.

  - A `BeforeAll` command may be placed directly inside a `Describe` command or - for more fine-grained control - inside a nested `Context` command.
- **Inside an individual `It` command**, in which case it applies to *that test only*.

---

In the context of your code, this means:

**`Context`-level `Mock`**:

```bash
Describe 'Get-Text' {
    It 'returns text "Some text; Other text"' {
        Get-Text | Should -Be 'Some text; Other text'
        } 

    Context 'With Mock' {

      BeforeAll {
        # Placing the Mock here works, and makes it take effect
        # for all tests in this context.
        Mock Get-FirstText { return 'Mock text' }
      }

      It 'returns text "Mock text; Other text" after mocking Get-FirstText' {
          Get-Text | Should -Be 'Mock text; Other text'
          } 

      # ... potentially more `It` commands to which the Mock applies.
    }
}
```

**`It`-level `Mock`**:

```bash
Describe 'Get-Text' {
    It 'returns text "Some text; Other text"' {
        Get-Text | Should -Be 'Some text; Other text'
        } 

    
    It 'returns text "Mock text; Other text" after mocking Get-FirstText' {
        # Placing the Mock here works, and makes it take effect
        # for this specific test only.
        Mock Get-FirstText { return 'Mock text' }
        Get-Text | Should -Be 'Mock text; Other text'
        } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks @mklement0, that worked perfectly.  I've been doing a bit of reading about Pester v4 --> v5 changes and I can see the underlying reason for avoiding loose code in the describe and context blocks comes down to the new Discovery and Run phases introduced in Pester v5.  For anyone else mystified as to why your test code is so thoroughly broken in Pester v5, see (1) https://pester-docs.netlify.app/docs/migrations/breaking-changes-in-v5, (2) https://pester-docs.netlify.app/docs/migrations/v4-to-v5, and (3) https://pester-docs.netlify.app/docs/usage/discovery-and-run

Comment: Another gotcha for Pester v5: In my real test code I had to import the module under test in a script-level `BeforeDiscovery` block, not a `BeforeAll` block (previously in Pester v4 I'd just done it at the head of the script).  I initially tried it in a `BeforeAll` and got an error `Discovery in {path to script file} failed with: System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException: No modules named '{module under test}' are currently loaded.`